# Migrating from H2 to Ehcache

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

My configuration was Hibernate + persistence + jpa + h2.
Now I have Hibernate + persistence + jpa + Ehcache.

I am trying to use ehcache without database.
Is it possible?

I want to reduce memory usage, H2 is taking 500mb of memory in my system.
I dont need a full database.
Just a cache system to handle few objects when the application is running.